# sharepoint 2010 with Kendo UI, REST, autocomplete

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript, jquery

User defined List in SP 2010, with Kendo UI code as below

does not display any data in for my simple 'autocomplete example' .

Here is the code

```
<script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                 $("#autoComplete").kendoAutoComplete({   

                    dataTextField: "English",                       
                    dataSource: {
                        type: "odata",
                        serverFiltering: true,
                        serverPaging: true,
                        pageSize: 20,                           
                        transport: {                                
                            read: "http://domain/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/Translator",                                                          
                            }
                    }
                  });
            });
        </script>
```

Any idea whats the problem ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: While we are at the other end, you need to find out and let us know the problem to get help. Try using fiddler to see what is happening. My first guess is, you are getting 401 unauthorized due to security.

Comment: I had two problems to it:
1. My List in SP2010 had an empty "Title" field.
2. I had a comma missing :(

When I created a new list without "title" it all worked.
thanks Prashant, it had luckily nothing to do with Security.